# Entity Framework Core 2.2 use scalar DBFunction to get property on list of foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, user-defined-functions

I have a model with a linked list of foreign keys i.e.

```
[Table("a"]
public class A {
    [Key]
    [Column("a_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<B> Bs { get; set; } = new List<B>();
}

[Table("b"]
public class B {
    [Key]
    [Column("b_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string MyFunctionValue { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("a_id")]
    public A A { get; set; }
}
```

I've then defined a function which links to a scalar sql function like so...

```
public static class MySqlFunctions {
    [DbFunction("MyFunction", "dbo")]
    public static string MyFunction(int bId) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and registered in my context like so...

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MySqlFunctions.MyFunction(default));
```

What I want to be able to do in my repository class is to grab the A records with the linked B records in a List with their MyFunctionValue value set to the return value of the function when ran against the id of B. Something like...

```
myContext.A
    .Include(a => a.Bs.Select(b => new B {
        Id = b.Id,
        MyFunctionValue = MySqlFunctions.MyFunction(b.Id)
    });
```

However with all the options I've tried so far I'm getting either a InvalidOperationException or NotImplementedException I guess because it can't properly convert it to SQL?

Is there any way I can write a query like this or is it too complex for EF to generate SQL for? I know there's a possibility I could use .FromSql but I'd rather avoid it if possible as it's a bit messy.

**EDIT:**

So I've managed to get it working with the following code but it's obviously a bit messy, if anyone has a better solution I'd be grateful.

```
myContext.A
    .Include(a => a.Bs)
    .Select(a => new {
        A = a,
        MyFunctionValues = a.Bs.Select(b => MySqlFunctions.MyFunction(b.Id))
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(aWithMfvs => {
        for (int i = 0; i < aWithMfvs.MyFunctionValues.Count(); i++) {
            aWithMfvs.A.Bs[i].MyFunctionValue = aWithMfvs.MyFunctionValues[i];
        }

        return aWithMfvs.A;
    })
    .AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you should consider with db functions:

- When you declare a DbFunction as static method, you don't have to register it with the modelBuilder
- Registering is only needed, when you would use Fluent API (which IMHO I recommend anyway in order to have you entities free of any dependencies)
- The return value, the method name and the count, type and order of the method parameters must match your code in the user defined function (UDF)

  - You named the method parameter as `bId`. Is it exactly the same in your UDF or rather as in the table like `b_id`?

Comment: Thanks for this it's all useful info I wasn't aware of. However I think the issue in my case is that it's just not able to convert my linq query into the appropriate SQL. Hence it then tries to call the function client side and throws the exception. I've made an edit with the code I've had to write to make it work but it's obviously less than ideal.


Also the modelBuilder.HasDbFunction seems to be needed for me. Some of the responses on this thread seem to imply that it's needed if the static function is outside of the dbcontext. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11295